# What plugin\gem do you advice to use in order to add tag functionalities to my web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, tagging

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to add tag functionalities to my web application.

Do you advice to use a plugin\gem? If so, what plugin\gem do you advice to use?

Comment: A [free quote](https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/121881520641277952) for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`acts-as-taggable-on` is an universal solution for tags implentation in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty. Checkout [ruby-toolbox for options](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_tagging).